# Custome middleware showing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: laravel, authentication

Trying to make a lock-screen in my app where there will be a button for logged in users to lock their account which is working fine but when user is on lock screen I want to restrict user to redirect to other pages via manual URL typing.

For that I used a simple middleware but I think its conflicting with Laravel's Auth redirects.

How can I separate these two middleware's redirect action?

Route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
Route::get('locked', 'LockController@lockuser')->name('lock')->middleware('lock');
});
```

Controller:

```
public function lockuser()
    {
        Session::put('locked', true);
        return view('lock');
    }
```

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if($request->session()->has('locked')){
        return redirect ('/locked');
      }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Kernal:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\lockUser::class,
        ],
      ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'lock' => \App\Http\Middleware\lockUser::class,
    ];
```

Comment: I have a hunch your auth middleware is redirecting to a route that re-triggers the same auth middleware. Try putting an error-log line just before the redirect. I suspect you'll see it get called a bunch of times before the page errors out.

Comment: How to add error-log line?

Comment: Just remove the `lock` middleware from your route: `Route::get('locked', 'LockController@lockuser')->name('lock');`. `lock` should be applied to all other routes you want to prevent access to.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter if I remove it user can manually type URL and access all pages without entering lock screen password.

Comment: For testing purpose I removed middleware chaining from 'locked' route and applied to route with I want block but still getting same error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: If your php.ini file has a php_errors path configured, you can simply use `error_log(__FILE__.': '.__LINE__);`. The default location is usually `/var/logs/php_errors.log`. Or you can use Laravel's `logger(__FILE__.': '.__LINE__)` helper, which typically goes to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. (Mind the logger.php config regarding what levels of logging _actually_ get written.)

Comment: @kmuenkel got this "[2020-04-17 18:26:24] local.DEBUG: C:\laragon\www\myapp\app\Http\Middleware\lockUser.php: 20" for 26 times, what does it mean?

Comment: 26 times? Yeah, it means you have a middleware that's redirecting to a route that uses the same middleware, triggering the same redirect, and so-on. You're actually looking at infinite recursion that the browser is just smart enough to put an end to. Looks like @DigitalDrifter actually spotted this already, all you and I did was further prove it. "/lock" is where you want a failed authentication to land, so you don't want "/lock" itself checking for authentication.

Comment: Yes, you both are correct and understood my mistake but as suggested I removed middleware from "lock" route and applied to other routes still showing same error, how to fix this?